# How can I roll back different kinds of changes in Git?

Tags: git, rollback

1. If I made some changes, but didn't do a `commit -m "my message`, how can I rollback to where I was?
2. If I did a `commit -m 'my message'` but didn't push to origin, how can I roll back?
3. If I did a `git pull origin` , now I don't like what I got, how can I roll back to where I was?
4. How can I get a list of what files are at the origin that have changed or are different from my local?

Comment: I think these are all covered pretty much explicitly in the documentation.

Comment: For the 4th one, I don't think there is a way, but you can fetch (rather than pull) and not merge (which pull does automatically) and compare the branches.

Comment: Is the first one: "I made some changes but didn't do a commit after my changes, how do I get back to before my changes?" or "I made some changes but didn't do a commit before my most recent changes, how do I get back to before my most recent changes?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `git reset --hard HEAD^`
2. `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`
3. `git reset --hard <shaSUM of the commit>`
4. `git fetch && git diff origin/<branch>`

references: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Comment: don't you have to fetch before you do the 4th one?